# PyQt5 calling class from different thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading, pyqt5

I'm using python 3 and pyqt5 to make a simple timer that rings an alarm once complete. For the timer I've just created a loop with that sleeps for one second. From what I understand I need to use threading to use a loop and have that loop update the UI without it freezing until the loop is complete.

The problem I'm having is once the loop is complete I want my function to call another class that is in a different thread. I've tried using QThread and threading and cant seem to work out how to make the loop call a class from a different thread.

```
import sys, time, threading
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QSound

# setting up the UI
class Ui_Form(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(303, 227)
        self.setWorkTxt = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(Form)
        self.setWorkTxt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 150, 141, 31))
        self.setWorkTxt.setObjectName("setWorkTxt")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 190, 141, 27))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.countDownTimer = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(Form)
        self.countDownTimer.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(13, 52, 281, 91))
        self.countDownTimer.setProperty("intValue", 0)
        self.countDownTimer.setObjectName("countDownTimer")
        self.retranslateUi(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Timer"))
        self.setWorkTxt.setPlainText(_translate("Form", "enter time"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Start"))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.start)

# this function creates a new thread and starts the timer
    def start(self):
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.timer, args=( ))
        t.start()

# timer function
    def timer(self):
        num = int(self.setWorkTxt.toPlainText())
        for i in range (1, num + 1):
            self.countDownTimer.display(i)
            time.sleep(1)
        audio.alarm() # this is where I want to call the class from the parent thread

# This is the alarm that I want to sound once the timer is finished
class audio(QSound):

    def alarm():
        QSound.play("alarm.wav")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_Form()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'm kinda new to python and Qt so I apologize if I got some of the terminology wrong or missed something simple.

Comment: Use PyQt5.QtCode.QTimer if you need a time. However if your goal was to learn about multi threads and Qt there is a lot more you have to know.

Comment: Thanks Barry Scott. I'm learning now that there is a lot more complexity to threads than I first thought.